# Procedure: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "QUARTER": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm new to Oracle PL/SQL and I'm attempting to create a procedure, called pop_date_dim, which populates an already-existing date dimension called date_dim. It does so by accepting both a date (DDMMYYYY) and a number (n) as parameters. The date dimension is then populated by using a FOR loop. Unfortunately, I keep getting two errors. Error(142,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignore and Error(152,13): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "QUARTER": invalid identifier.

This is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pop_date_dim (DDMMYYYY IN number, n IN number)
IS 
start_date date;
BEGIN
start_date := TO_DATE(DDMMYYYY, 'DDMMYYYY');
    FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
        INSERT INTO date_dim
            VALUES ( 
            start_date + i, 
            dayofweek(start_date + i), 
            dayofmonth(start_date + i), 
            dayofyear(start_date + i),
            dayname(start_date + i),
            month(start_date + i),
            monthname(start_date + i) + i,
            year(start_date + i),
            quarter(start_date + i)
            ); 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

It seems to have something to do with Oracle's quarter() function, which ought to return an integer in the range 1 to 4. I can't see what the problem is at all. Any advice or pointers?

Comment: Oracle's list of built-in functions don't seem to have Quarter. See: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm to calculate the quarter given a date, see: https://www.foxinfotech.in/2018/09/how-to-get-quarter-from-date-in-oracle.html. If you are sure the function exists, show the table definition you are trying to insert into.

Comment: Note that Oracle also doesn't have `year`, `month`, `dayofmonth`, etc. as built-in functions.  I'd expect those were all supposed to reference user-defined functions in your schema.

Comment: If you're not sure how an Oracle function should work, check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/book-index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those functions, presumably from MySQL DB, within the VALUES list don't exists within the Oracle DB, and should be translated.

Indeed no need to populate a table's columns with those converted values, since you can get them all by using suitable `TO_CHAR()` conversion for each within a SELECT statement, but for sake of your case that procedure might be rewritten as considering Oracle DB

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pop_date_dim(DDMMYYYY IN VARCHAR2, n IN INT) IS
  start_date DATE;
BEGIN
  start_date := TO_DATE(DDMMYYYY, 'DDMMYYYY');
  FOR i IN 1 .. n LOOP
    INSERT INTO date_dim
    VALUES
      (start_date + i,
       TO_CHAR(start_date + i, 'D', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
       TO_CHAR(start_date + i, 'DD'),
       TO_CHAR(start_date + i, 'DDD'),
       TO_CHAR(start_date + i, 'Day', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
       TO_CHAR(start_date + i, 'MM'),
       TO_CHAR(start_date + i, 'Month', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
       TO_CHAR(start_date + i, 'YYYY'),
       TO_CHAR(start_date + i, 'Q'));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

where you should make the first parameter to be of string type rather than a numeric one against for the cases of having that values with leading zero

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cdf67a4abbf4ac7ba0a500b7d9944530)</kbd>

Comment: A very good answer, but be aware of the DDMMYYYY parameter being numeric. 01012021 is just 1012021 and will result in a wrong date. Use `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(ddmmyyyy, 'FM00000000'), 'DDMMYYYY')` instead. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f09d9106183cb037827cef09b8e499e4

Comment: You may want to use `'fmDay'` and `'fmMonth'` to get rid of spaces. `'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'` has no effect on the day of the week unfortunately. It is the `NLS_TERRITORY` that is being used, which cannot be set in `TO_CHAR`. You can see my feature request to get the ISO day with `TO_CHAR` here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4400537/add-iso-day-to-format-model-for-date-functions. In more than two years it only got 5 upvotes :-( But Sven W shows a workaround in the discussion: `trunc(:date) - trunc(:date,'IW') + 1`.

Comment: For 1 = Sunday as in MySQL, that would even have to be `mod(trunc(:date) - trunc(:date, 'IW') + 1, 7) + 1`.

Comment: yes indeed `iw` formatting is always a cornerstone in my mind, but this usage, which I mostly met within postings of Wernfried, is interesting ... @ThorstenKettner , and as far as I remember it was an effective method in order to solve such issues through use of American-Turkish NLS parameters settings mix during my woring days with Oracle Forms :)

Answer (score 1):

None of the functions used are built in Oracle functions, they may user defined but Oracle does provide `to_char(some_date,'fmt')` where the fmt code can provide each of the values you looking need, including `quarter`. See [to_char](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F). Further there is no need to loop through dates. You can do this is a single statement, or build it into a procedure.

```
create or replace procedure pop_date_dim(
                            start_date     in date
                          , number_of_days in number
                          )
is    
begin 
     insert into date_dim(
                <list of columns> 
               ) 
     with date_list (each_date) as 
          ( select start_date + (level-1) 
              from dual connect by level <= number_of_days
          ) 
    select <list of values> 
      from date_list;
end pop_date_dim;
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=79611e4f17d8dca5f054b3a62c86a1ac). The demo only does some of the fields, be should be enough show the process.